# Corona source of gravity is body

Tags: lua, physics, coronasdk

I want to make a moon rotating around a planet, or something along that analogy. So is there something I can call for `physics.setGravity(0,0)` that changes the position that the gravity pulls towards, particularly assigning that to be a physics body? If not, simply a specific x-y coordinate will be fine.

```
local moon = display.newImage ("moon.png")
physics.addBody(moon, {bounce=0, density=1.0})
local earth = display.newImage ("earth.png")
physics.addBody(earth, {bounce=0, density=1.0})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of playing around with the `setGravity` option, I think you should just rotate the images using something like this:

```
local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()
physics.setGravity(0, 0)
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

local background = display.newImage( "space.png", true )
background.x = display.contentWidth / 2
background.y = display.contentHeight / 2

local earth = display.newImage( "earth.png" )
earth.x = 100; earth.y = 200
earth.xScale = 0.7
earth.yScale = 0.7
physics.addBody( earth, {radius=40 } )
earth.bodyType = "static"

local moon = display.newImage( "moon.png", 40, 40)
moon.x = earth.x + 80
moon.y = earth.y
moon.xScale = 0.3
moon.yScale = 0.3
moon.rotation = 100  
physics.addBody( moon, {radius=10 } )
moon.bodyType = "dynamic"

myJoint = physics.newJoint( "pivot", moon, earth, earth.x, earth.y )

local orbit = function( event )    
        moon.rotation = moon.rotation + 1.5
end
```

Notice that I am not really mucking about with `setGravity`, but the speed of the rotation is defined in the `orbit` function.

The above code assumes you just have image files to represent your planetary bodies. If so, you will have to play around with the constants above (`earth.x` and `earth.y`, scaling values, etc) to make the whole system LOOK right for the images you choose.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

No - you can change gravity but it will pull/push only in the direction you have it set to, never to any point. You'd likely use a sensor (invisible) around your earth and apply force to draw things towards it when the collision event between the moon/other and sensor began.